# MSCV 2010 incorrect behaviour of --someNumber operator

Tags: c++, operators, visual-studio-2010

In my code, I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
for(unsigned int n=10; n > 1; --n)
{
  std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

I expect the output:

> 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

The output I got:

> 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2

I get the expected output when using gnu/g++, but not in MSVC 2010.

I know I get the expected results with that loop by doing:

```
for(unsigned int n=9; n > 0; n--)
{
  std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

Does anyone else get this behaviour, or did I somehow throw some sort of magic switch accidently?

Comment: Interesting, how did you manage to get "expected" output when using gnu/g++ ...

Comment: My g++ (and clang++) both give the actual expected output, which is the same as the MSVC output. You must have thrown the "make g++ behave badly" switch.

Comment: Here is a [demo running g+1 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/pY53FC). The output is the same as what you claim for MSVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic there, the decrement happens after the first iteration of the loop. That's how `for` loops work. It makes no difference whether it's `n--` or `--n`.

Comment: I was under the impression that --n would be evaluated at the beginning of the loop rather than at the end.  Makes me a little confused why my code gave that output in Ubuntu, though.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop can (loosely)[1] made from using `while`:

```
for(A; B; C)
{
   content of loop;
}
```

becomes:

```
A;
while(B)
{
  content of loop;
  C;
}
```

So, in other words:

```
unsigned int n=10;
while(n > 1)
{
  std::cout << n << std::endl;
  --n;
}
```

Now, you can see clearly why it's doing what it's doing.

[1] Of course, with the above "conversion", the scope of `n` changes, and this is not meant to show how the compiler produces the code for a `for` loop - it is just to explain how the loop operates.